# Unable to disable a textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, text

Depending on which option I choose in the above drop down box, it is supposed to either gray the text boxes out, or let the user type in them. I am using the following:

```
document.getElementById(\'freq2\').disabled=true;
```

This does not work. But, I can use the following just fine, and it successfully disappears:

```
document.getElementById(\'freq2\').style.display = \'none\';
```

Why can I not gray out the text boxes, but I can hide them, and change their colors, etc.?

Comment: The property is `disabled`, not `disable`

Comment: Sorry, that it was I have. It is not working. Will edit above. Any other tips?

Comment: It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/6A8Zd/ Why are you escaping the quotes? Are these statements part of another string?

Comment: Why are your quotes escaped? That's the problem.

Comment: I have a php file generating and returning HTML so I have to escape the quotes

Comment: So have you confirmed that the quotes are output in the rendered source correctly?

Comment: If you are using php, are you wrapping the overall string in single `'` or double quotes `"`, if it's that latter then you don't need to escape the single quotes, or they will render incorrectly.

Comment: Yes. Ok so I found something out. I was using a div tag to attempt to gray out multiple boxes at a time (I can hide multiple at a time with this method). 

I changed the individual ID to one of the boxes to freq2 and that worked just fine. Is there a way to mass gray out the boxes like there is with hiding them?

Comment: Use a JavaScript loop to iterate over each of them and disable them, or wrap them in a `<fieldset disabled> ... textboxes here </fieldset>`

Comment: Thanks for replies. I'm not too experienced with javascript. What is the proper syntax for something like this?

Comment: @user2537383 Have updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unescape your quotes.

```
document.getElementById(\'freq2\').disabled=true;
```

needs to be

```
document.getElementById('freq2').disabled=true;
```

or the JavaScript won't be valid, so it won't disable it.

---

You can wrap multiple textboxes in a `fieldset`

```
<fieldset id="myfields" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myfields").disabled = true;
```

CSS to remove border:

```
fieldset {
    border: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pCr6/)

Comment: I can mass disable them, thanks. It did create some ugly border around it, messing with my format, though. Any tips?

Comment: @user2537383 You can hide it using the CSS I have added in my question. If it has helped you please upvote, and mark as answer. Thanks

Comment: I definitely will mark yours. Thanks for all the help. Just one last thing (hopefully). How can I have the boxes enable by default rather than disabled?

Comment: You're welcome. Just remove `disabled="disabled"` from the `fieldset`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `disabled` property (not disable). Also, no need to escape your quotes

`document.getElementById('freq2').disable=true;`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6A8Zd/)**

Comment: Sorry, that it was I have. It is not working. Will edit above. Any other tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of theese:

```
document.getElementById(\'freq2\').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Or

```
document.getElementById(\'freq2\').setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/javitube/wzzHC/